# can this trim code ever fail?

Tags: c#

I recently bumped into an exception in my code because I was trimming a null string.
I replaced it with the following:

```
  SomeValue = (SomeString ?? "").Trim();
```

Can this code ever fail?

Thanks.

Note: I know I can add a try/catch; I'm just looking to make this line fail-proof without using a try/catch.

Comment: Could you write some small unit tests to test?

Comment: I suspect the answer within your scope is no, it cannot fail. The only reason it would fail in normal operation is running out of memory.

Comment: It fails in a much more grotesque way.  It produces garbage data and you won't know it.

Comment: The real bug was not that you called Trim() on a null string, the bug was that you forgot to initialize the string.  That bug will now be hideously hidden, generating wrong output in a completely different section of the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not fail (ie. throw a `NullReferenceException`), assuming `SomeString` is indeed a `string`.

You could achieve the same in many ways:

```
SomeValue = (SomeString == null)?string.Empty:SomeString.Trim();
```

Comment: ok, thanks Oded. This is part of a custom json deserializer and I had an error come up in a process that cannot fail.

Comment: @frenchie - When you write code like this, think about making it as _readable_ as possible.

Comment: @Oded, I would be a little more precise: `This will not fail (throw a NullReferenceException)` as this code can fail in other ways.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - fair point... of course an `OutOfMemoryExcpetion` could always occur.

Comment: @Oded: if I deploy on Azure, are  OutOfMemoryExecptions automatically cured by the fact that Azure scales dynamically? I know this might sound naive but I just curious.

Comment: @frenchie - I doubt it. Azure is an abstraction, the code still runs in real memory and may end up consuming all of it in a single process.

Comment: ok, I thought so too but hoped that Azure could help for that.

Comment: @frenchie, on Azure you will get `System.OutOfCreditException` before you get `System.OutOfMemoryException` :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Even better :)?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the way I would have done it, but no, this shouldn't ever fail now.

I'd probably write an extension method that calls trim after checking for null.  Something like this:

```
public static string NullTrim(this String str) {
    if(str == null) {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return str.Trim();
}
```

This allows all of the following to compile and execute without error:

```
    "".NullTrim();
    "  test  ".NullTrim();
    ((string)null).NullTrim();
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the idea; for the moment I'm going with the line I have.

Answer (score 2):

Well if it was failing because of `NullReferenceException`, then now it will definitely not fail **because of that**. As for the rest, I cannot say without context.